# How to shuffle divs but don't kill their events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
  $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
    inDuration: 300,
    outDuration: 225,
    constrain_width: true, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
    hover: false,          // Activate on click
    alignment: 'right',    // Aligns dropdown to left or right edge (works with constrain_width)
    gutter: 0,             // Spacing from edge
    belowOrigin: false     // Displays dropdown below the button
  });
  $("#shuffle").bind('click', shuffle);

  function shuffle() {
    $(".facts").each(function() {
      var divs = $(this).children('div');
      for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) $(divs[i]).remove();
      var i = divs.length;
      if (i == 0) return false;

      while (--i) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tempi = divs[i];
        var tempj = divs[j];
        divs[i] = tempj;
        divs[j] = tempi;
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        $(divs[i]).appendTo(this);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

It shuffles all divs inside .facts by removing them and then appending, but, as far as I understood it kills all events, so the first part initializes components of materializecss, the second is a function to shuffle the elements.
While elements are not shuffled dropdown works, as soon as you used Shuffle - Dropdown is not working ...

Comment: Can you post your markups ? or can you http://jsfiddle.net/ it ?

Comment: Use jQuery's .clone(), then remove the original element. It will copy the events of the element too! More info here: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery's `detach()` function instead of `remove()`.

From the docs, it says:

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

Source:
https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.clone` you may then copy elements with their attached events... 
To follow you logic, I have booked cloned divs in `newDivs` array so I could append them to the current element.

```
$(".facts").each(function() {
  var divs = $(this).children('div'),
    newDivs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    newDivs.push(divs[i].clone(true));
    $(divs[i]).remove();
  }
  var i = newDivs.length;
  if (i == 0) return false;
  while (--i) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var tempi = newDivs[i];
    var tempj = newDivs[j];
    newDivs[i] = tempj;
    newDivs[j] = tempi;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < newDivs.length; i++) {
    $(newDivs[i]).appendTo(this);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't remove them.

If you append an element that's already in the document elsewhere, then it will *move* there with no other effects.

That said, I'm not 100% certain about jQuery behaving like that. It *should*, but I can't guarantee it. Prefer JS's native `this.appendChild(newDivs[i]);` instead.